# I would like to add column for table in Grafana and AWS Timestream

Tags: amazon-web-services, grafana

I have data like this picture from AWS Timestream
[image]

so I'm trying to make a table from this data.
I wrote query like this to add 'ntu'
[image]

```
SELECT CREATE_TIME_SERIES(time,measure_value::double) as ntu FROM $__database.$__table where $__timeFilter and measure_name = 'ntu'
```

However I do not know how to add more columns such as 'shutterspeed', 'intensity' by query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pivot the table on measure_name like this:

```
select device_id, time
       max(case when measure_name = 'ntu' then measure_value::double end) as ntu,
       max(case when measure_name = 'shutterspeed' then measure_value::bigint end) as shutterspeed,
       max(case when measure_name = 'intensity' then measure_value::double end) as intensity
from $__database.$__table where $__timeFilter
group by instance_id, time
```

Similarly you can add other columns